# How do I retrieve the API data from the LinkedIn Strategy for Opauth?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I installed the Google Opauth Strategy and it's working brilliantly. The LinkedIn one acts a little differently; in the directions for this strategy it specifies that no OAuth Redirect URL is needed (on the LinkedIn Developer website). I tried leaving this out, and kept getting this error:

'Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key.'

This error is also on the demo for the plugin here: http://opauth.org/#demo

So I changed it up a bit and placed my redirect URL there just in case, like my Google one has, and it seemed to have worked! It took me to the LinkedIn login screen, I put in my credentials, and it redirected me back to my application. The trouble is, no data was returned this time.

My defaults in LinkedInStrategy.php looks like this:

```
public $defaults = array(
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/users/login',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope' => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_contactinfo'
);
```

In my controller I have this:

```
$_SESSION['log'] = $this->data;
```

And in my view I have this:

```
debug($_SESSION['log']);
```

This is just to see if the data is setting. When I log in with GoogleStrategy.php settings, this line displays all of the data and I use it to log me in. Perfect. But with the LinkedIn strategy, I just get an empty array. Anybody have any ideas?

Edit:

According to the LinkedIn API documentation [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication), my code returned is the correct code returned upon successful authentication (redirect uri, code, and state in the response URL). So I know everything's correct thus far to connect, just obtaining the data must be different than the $this->data return method stated in the regular Opauth documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I changed the redirect_uri back to default:

```
'redirect_uri' => '{complete_url_to_strategy}oauth2callback',
```

In the LinkedIn Developer API area, I placed this URL in the OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs:

```
http://example.com/auth/linkedin/oauth2callback
```

So the OAuth Redirect URL DOES need to be set, unlike their instructions [here](https://github.com/opauth/linkedin).

```
2. Create LinkedIn application at https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer

    Enter your domain at JavaScript API Domain
    There is no need to enter OAuth Redirect URL
```

Furthermore, it specifically has to be http://www.example.com/auth/linkedin/oauth2callback. If it is not that URL exactly, it will not work, unless you change some of the config files yourself and the name of functions. My error was that I set a custom page for it to go to, rather than going through its oath2callback function THEN heading to the redirect page.